# top aligning dynamically sized objects vertically with css

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align the top left corners of two dynamically created objects. The smaller rectangle on the top holds some descriptive text, the larger rectangle contains an image.
Problem is, i can't position the elements using position:absolute, because there are several sets on the page, loaded dynamically from a database.

That's how it should look:

http://soundtrax.at/aligning_objects.gif

Using position:relative doesn't work, because the position of the following object relates to the bottom of the previous one. What can I do to sort of set the top left corners of the elements as reference points?

Comment: Can you create fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/X7KkN/3/ it works if i change the size of the image rectangle, but not if i add some more text to the top one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute`.

Make sure that the image and text are wrapped around a container with the following CSS:

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
 }
```

Now if you use `position: absolute` for the elements inside `.wrap`, it will work, and position itself relative to `.wrap` :)

```
.text {
   position: absolute;
   top: -5px;
   left: -5px;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/msR77/